# Is it possible for Swift to inherit from an lightweight generic Objective-c Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have two classes, the base class is in Obj-c and the subclass is in Swift.

The Obj-c class uses new XCode 7's lightweight generic feature defined as follows:

```
@interface BaseController<T: SFObject *> : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong) T model;
@end
```

That works fine for Obj-c subclasses.

Now for Swift if I define the generic type as I usually do I get the following error:

> Cannot specialize non-generic type 'BaseObjcController'.

My second class is defined as follows:

```
class SwiftController: BaseObjcController<SFUser> {

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** As of **Swift 3,** Objective-C lightweight generics *are* imported into Swift. For more information, see

- [SE-0057 Importing Objective-C Lightweight Generics](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0057-importing-objc-generics.md)
- [Using Imported Lightweight Generics in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_lightweight_generics_in_swift)

---

*Old answer:* From [Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID173):

> NOTE
>
> Aside from these Foundation collection classes, Objective-C
>   lightweight generics are ignored by Swift. Any other types using
>   lightweight generics are imported into Swift as if they were
>   unparameterized.

So this is not possible at present. As you can see from the
"Generated Interface" assistant view, your Objective-C class is imported
to Swift as

```
public class BaseController : UIViewController {
    public var model: SFObject!
}
```

This was also discussed in the Apple Developer Forum:

- [Objective-C generics not visible from Swift?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7394)

Feel free to file an enhancement bug report!