# Swift: How to initialize with generics

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generics

I am trying to bridge and use an objective-c library [(this one)](https://github.com/nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary/) in my swift project. Interface goes like this. But how on earth I can initialize and use this with Swift?!

```
@interface MutableOrderedDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType> : OrderedDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType>
```

And this is how I exactly want to define my dictionary in swift file:

```
class TransactionView{
   var tableSections =  MutableOrderedDictionary<String, Array<Transaction>>()
   ..
}
```

But this and all other variations I tried, Xcode found something to complain about my syntax

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628297/is-it-possible-for-swift-to-inherit-from-an-lightweight-generic-objective-c-clas. The Objective-C lightweight generics are ignored in Swift. You can only create `let tableSections = MutableOrderedDictionary()`.

Comment: @MartinR  Tnx! Does that mean I should stop trying to use that library or I create MutableOrderedDictionary() then cast all values to Array<Transaction> while reading

Comment: *If* you use that library then you have to cast all `AnyObject`s to your actual type. There exist native Swift implementations of ordered dictionaries as well. I don't have experience with any of them, so I cannot make any recommendation.